# Muted howling noise at about 2000rpm Nissan Micra K12 2005

Tags: nissan, noise, manual-transmission

Recently when I drive I noticed this noise which tends to come around 2000rpm. Going through the gears I can't hear anything through first and second, then it starts in this rev band through 3rd and especially 4th at lower speeds say 35mph-45mph. I looked under the car at the muffler to see if there was a hole under it but it looks sound. Any idea what might be causing the problem? Its not got any worse. I drive about 40 miles in it per day. It is a manual.

Comment: Is this a manual shift transmission?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Can you record the noise and post it? Where is it coming from? The front, left, right, rear?

Comment: It is coming from the back, but you can't hear it in 1st or 2nd. It is progressive, dull, low-mid range tonally, sounds like it is under the car.

Comment: It's almost impossible to really translate a sound through the written word.  Anything you could do to get a good recording of the sound to post into your question would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It was the wheel bearing which was causing the problem.